# How to change the default size of <h1>...<h7> tags in Android WebView?

Tags: android, html, css

I'm specifying some HTML text like this in the strings.xml file of my Android app:

```
<string>

    <h4>title</h4><br/>
           some text
</string>
```

1) How can I change the size of the text for the h4 tag? I've changed the default text size of my app in styles.xml to 23sp, but for the h4 tag I want it to be for example 28sp.

2) Is it possible to change the text size for buttons and textviews in the theme for the whole app? I want all of my textviews to have 23sp size and buttons to have 26sp.

Comment: People should really stop downvoting questions that are not bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using a WebView, you can use CSS to style anything.  E.g., to change the style of the <h1>, <h2>, <h3> tags and <form> buttons, you might use

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Your title goes here</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            h1 { font-size: 28px; font-weight: bold; text-align: center; }
            h2 { font-size: 24px; font-weight: bold; text-align: center; }
            h3 { font-size: 22px; text-align: center; }
            input[type=submit],
            input[type=button],
            input[type=reset] {
                font-size: 110%;
            }
        </style>
```

There are many choices for specifying the font size -- you can use ems, pixels (px), points (pt), percentages (e.g. 120%), etc.  You can also generate portions of the CSS style at runtime -- this would allow you to convert from Android dp/sp units to pixels, and then use the calculated pixel value to specify the font-size in "px" units.

It is not possible to use CSS in Html.fromHtml(), so you wouldn't be able to use this in a TextView, for example.

Comment: thanks for the answer ,but is it ok to use a WebView ? i mean its an android app and all devices support using webviews?  by the way im still wondering about my main question to change the default h1...h7 tags text size

Comment: The HTML fragment that I showed above will change the style of the h1 tag.  You can add similar sections for h2, h3, h4, etc.  You can change the size in pixels to be whatever you want, or convert from Android dp/sp units at runtime to make the HTML font size match Android's. As for using a WebView, use it if you need to. The only problem with WebView is that it takes longer to display than a TextView. If you can get by with much more limited styling (almost primitive), then you can use a TextView and the Html.fromHtml() method.

Comment: thanks a lot Yojimbo for the explanation.but what if i dont use a webView? the code you gave me is for changing the size of h1 tag in a webView .but what if i use TextView and the Html.fromHtml() method only.then how can i change the size of h1 tag? thank you very much for helping

Comment: You will not be able to change the behavior of the h1 tag (or any other tag) if you use Html.fromHtml().